# Azure Search: Frequency of calling indexer

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-logic-apps

For an Azure Search service, I am looking to get updates reflected closest to real-time. I can execute it via REST API using a logic app with recurrence.

If I invoke the logic app very frequently(ever 3 seconds). Is there a catch to this approach?

- can the indexer get blocked because of too frequent calls?
- is there any cost-implication of this constant invocation (either on logic app or on azure search)

I am trying to see if I can avoid building logic to determine various scenarios when the indexer needs to be called. (can get complex)

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK with indexer running every 5 minutes, you don't need to invoke it at all - it can run on a schedule.

If you need to invoke indexer more frequently, you can run it once every 3 minutes on a free tier service, and as often as you want on any paid tier service. If an indexer is already running when you run it, the call will fail with a `409` status.

However, if you need to run indexer very frequently, usually it's in response to new data arriving and you have that data in hand. In that case, it may be more efficient to directly index that data using the push-style indexing API. See [Add, update, or delete documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents) for REST API reference, or you can use [Azure Search .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-dotnet-sdk)

Comment: thanks- could you explain more about 'push-style indexingAPI'

Comment: Added links to my answer.